# Magento 1.9 - Multiple websites viewing locally

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore

This is definitely a noob question, but after creating multiple websites in a single Magento 1.9 instance, how do I view each store?  When I visit http://127.0.0.1:8888/, only the default website is visible.  Here is a screenshot of my store setup.  I would like to view store "test" or "test2", but only the "Main Website" store/products are visible.  Thanks for any direction you can give.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to System->configuration->web->Url options -> Add Store Code to Urls

and set yes.

now you can open your store using  siteurl/test/